# Custom Gutenberg-Block esnext pass variables

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I am trying to create a Block with [@wordpress/create-block](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/create-block), for this you have to use exnext. I`m not pretty good with JS at the moment, still learning.

So far it is working (the block appears in the editor).

The files are created with separate files and export functions.

index.js with

```
import Edit from './edit';

/**
* @see ./edit.js
*/
edit: Edit,
```

edit.js with

```
export default function Edit({className, props}) {

    console.log(props);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                Text
            </p>
        </div>
    )

}
```

The className is available in the Edit function `export default function Edit({className}) { ... }`, but I cannot get `props` variable.

Comment: Did you follow the [tutorial](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/create-block/) before you actually used the @wordpress/create-block package to create your block? You could also [start with a simple block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/) before using the `create-block` command.

Comment: Yes, es5 blocks are working, `props` is properly displaying if I put the function inline: `edit(props) {console.log(props); ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your "edit" file is that your `Edit()` function in there is [*unpacking/destructuring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the props, hence `props` is no longer defined or what you expected it to be.

So you should do `function Edit( props )` and not `function Edit({className, props})` — and it should be noted that `className` is in that props, i.e. `props.className`.

```js
function Edit( props ) {
  console.log( props.className, props );
}

// .. Or when unpacking the props object:

// Assuming your block got an attribute named myAttribute.
function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes, className } ) {
  console.log( className, attributes.myAttribute );
}
```

I hope that helps and I suggest you to check, if you haven't already done so, the block editor handbook, e.g. the ["Edit and Save" section](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/).

BTW, you don't actually have that `import Edit from './edit';` in the `edit.js` file, do you?

Comment: That import ind the edit.js was a mistake, I corrected that, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, that pointed me in the right direction. The function Edit has the comment: @param {Object} [props] Properties passed from the editor. So they already contain the content, which I misunderstood. Also I looked at https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/create-block/attributes/. I missed some things, it is working now.